# I'm new to coding and trying to create a map using googles api. For some reason im getting 5 errors on my index.html and cant seem to fix

Tags: html, api, visual-studio-2010

[here's my code. I can see the errors but unsure what to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHtun.png)

the errors say that their is not closing tags i might be blind but im pretty sure they all are there

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

The last script tag on your head tag should be:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Not:

```
<script src="script.js"</script>
```

You're missing '>' on your script tag

Comment: thank you sir i was pulling my hair out all day trying to figure this out

Comment: @jablinski no problem. If you want to avoid syntax errors in the future, you may want to use a vscode extension called prettier, sometimes if not always it catches this errors and autocorrect it

Comment: Your HTML is thoroughly invalid. There is no such thing as `</>` in HTML. @jablinski While this may "work", do NOT use it.

Comment: @Rob my bad forgot the script inside the </>